# Error within Logstash for the ELK stack -- Unsure after days of debugging

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

The only non-commented out line of my logstash.conf is:

```
  path.config: "C:/ELK/logstash-7.15.0-windows-x86_64/logstash-7.15.0/config/logstash-sample.conf"
```

My only non commented out section is of my pipeline.yml:

```
- pipeline.id: log_files
#
#   # The configuration string to be used by this pipeline
#   config.string: "input { generator {} } filter { sleep { time => 1 } } output { stdout { codec => dots } }"

#   # The path from where to read the configuration text
  path.config: "C:/ELK/logstash-7.15.0-windows-x86_64/logstash-7.15.0/config/logstash-sample.conf"
```

If I simply run `logstash.bat` within the bin:

```
[2021-10-11T14:40:51,933][ERROR][logstash.config.sourceloader] No configuration found in the configured sources.
```

If I run: `logstash.bat -f C:\ELK\logstash-7.15.0-windows-x86_64\logstash-7.15.0\config\logstash-sample.conf`

```
C:\ELK\logstash-7.15.0-windows-x86_64\logstash-7.15.0\bin>logstash.bat -f C:\ELK\logstash-7.15.0-windows-x86_64\logstash-7.15.0\config\logstash-sample.conf
"Using bundled JDK: ""
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Sending Logstash logs to C:/ELK/logstash-7.15.0-windows-x86_64/logstash-7.15.0/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2021-10-11T14:38:51,311][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Log4j configuration path used is: C:\ELK\logstash-7.15.0-windows-x86_64\logstash-7.15.0\config\log4j2.properties
[2021-10-11T14:38:51,327][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.15.0", "jruby.version"=>"jruby 9.2.19.0 (2.5.8) 2021-06-15 55810c552b OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.11+9 on 11.0.11+9 +indy +jit [mswin32-x86_64]"}
[2021-10-11T14:38:51,421][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2021-10-11T14:38:53,230][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2021-10-11T14:38:53,465][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of [ \\t\\r\\n], \"#\", [A-Za-z0-9_-], '\"', \"'\", [A-Za-z_], \"-\", [0-9], \"[\", \"{\" at line 13, column 37 (byte 250) after filter{\ncsv{\nseparator=>\",\"\ncolumns=>[\"ip\",\"date\",\"time\",\"zone\",", :backtrace=>["C:/ELK/logstash-7.15.0-windows-x86_64/logstash-7.15.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:32:in `compile_imperative'", "org/logstash/execution/AbstractPipelineExt.java:187:in `initialize'", "org/logstash/execution/JavaBasePipelineExt.java:72:in `initialize'", "C:/ELK/logstash-7.15.0-windows-x86_64/logstash-7.15.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:47:in `initialize'", "C:/ELK/logstash-7.15.0-windows-x86_64/logstash-7.15.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:52:in `execute'", "C:/ELK/logstash-7.15.0-windows-x86_64/logstash-7.15.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:391:in `block in converge_state'"]}
[2021-10-11T14:38:53,559][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Logstash shut down.
[2021-10-11T14:38:53,575][FATAL][org.logstash.Logstash    ] Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
org.jruby.exceptions.SystemExit: (SystemExit) exit
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:747) ~[jruby-complete-9.2.19.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:710) ~[jruby-complete-9.2.19.0.jar:?]
        at C_3a_.ELK.logstash_minus_7_dot_15_dot_0_minus_windows_minus_x86_64.logstash_minus_7_dot_15_dot_0.lib.bootstrap.environment.<main>(C:\ELK\logstash-7.15.0-windows-x86_64\logstash-7.15.0\lib\bootstrap\environment.rb:94) ~[?:?]
```

Comment: For the first one I suggest using "--log.level debug --config.debug --config.test_and_exit" and see what it logs about where it is trying to read the configuration from. For the second one, what immediately follows `columns=>["ip","date","time","zone",` in your configuration? If it is a curly quote, change it to a straight quote.

Comment: @Badger Yes. That was the issue, but I still had to specify `logstash.bat -f C:\ELK\logstash-7.15.0-windows-x86_64\logstash-7.15.0\config\logstash-sample.conf` Was there something wrong within my YAML files?

Comment: The debug options I suggested would cause it log where it is looking for the configuration. You seem to be assuming that path.settings has a certain value.